# How to Force Word to Embed Images when Converting from HTML to RTF?

Tags: html, ms-word, rtf, office-automation

I'm using Word's automation features to convert an HTML file with images into an RTF file.

Problem is that Word does not embed the images in the RTF file, instead using `INCLUDEPICTURE` to reference the images externally. The knock-on effect of this is that the Windows Rich Edit control ignores this keyword and no images are rendered.

```
LPDISPATCH lpd = docs.Open(COleVariant(sHtmlFilename),  // FileName
                    varFalse,                           // ConfirmConversions
                    varFalse,                           // ReadOnly
                    varFalse,                           // AddToRecentFiles
                    varNull,                            // PasswordDocument
                    varNull,                            // PasswordTemplate
                    varTrue,                            // Revert
                    varNull,                            // WritePasswordDocument
                    varNull,                            // WritePasswordTemplate
                    COleVariant(wdOpenFormatWebPages),  // Format
                    COleVariant(msoEncodingAutoDetect), // Encoding
                    varFalse,                           // Visible
                    varFalse,                           // OpenAndRepair
                    varZero,                            // DocumentDirection
                    varTrue,                            // NoEncodingDialog
                    varNull);                           // XMLTransform


if (lpd == NULL)
    return FALSE;

_Document doc(lpd);

doc.SaveAs(COleVariant(sRtfFilename),               // FileName
                COleVariant(wdSaveFormatRTF),       // FileFormat
                varFalse,                           // LockComments
                varNull,                            // Password
                varFalse,                           // AddToRecentFiles
                varNull,                            // WritePassword
                varFalse,                           // ReadOnlyRecommended
                varFalse,                           // EmbedTrueTypeFonts
                varFalse,                           // SaveNativePictureFormat
                varFalse,                           // SaveFormsData
                varFalse,                           // SaveAsAOCELetter
                COleVariant(msoEncodingAutoDetect), // Encoding
                varFalse,                           // InsertLineBreaks
                varFalse,                           // AllowSubstitutions
                varOne,                             // LineEnding
                varFalse);                          // AddBiDiMarks
```

My question then is: Are there other features in the Automation model that will force Word to embed the images in the RTF?

Note: I am currently trying to manually embed the images by post-processing the RTF but it's an inelegant and possibly fragile solution.

Answer (score 3):

I had recently run into the same issue and managed to solve it that way:

```
procedure TMWnd.UnlinkImages(ADoc: Variant);
var
    fCnt, sCnt, iCnt, i  : Cardinal;
    field, shape, ishape  : Variant;
begin
    fCnt := ADoc.Fields.Count;
    for i:=1 to fCnt do begin
        field := ADoc.Fields.Item(i);
        if VarIsClear(field)or VarIsClear(field.LinkFormat) then
            Continue;
        if field.Type <> wdFieldIncludePicture then
            Continue;
        field.LinkFormat.SavePictureWithDocument := True;
        field.LinkFormat.BreakLink;
    end;


    sCnt := ADoc.Shapes.Count;
    for i:=1 to sCnt do begin
        shape := ADoc.Shapes.Item(i);
        if VarIsNull(shape)or VarIsClear(shape.LinkFormat) then
            continue;
        shape.LinkFormat.SavePictureWithDocument := True;
        shape.LinkFormat.BreakLink;
    end;

    iCnt := ADoc.InlineShapes.Count;
    for i:=1 to iCnt do begin
        ishape := ADoc.InlineShapes.Item(i);
        if VarIsClear(ishape)or VarIsClear(ishape.LinkFormat) then
            Continue;
        ishape.LinkFormat.SavePictureWithDocument := True;
        ishape.LinkFormat.BreakLink;
    end;
end;
```

This is Delphi code, but it could be easily adapted to any language since it is simple OLE Automation method calls.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. I've been Googling for this for hours.

Answer (score 2):

I needed to translate it to VBscript.
Maybe it'll be useful for someone.

```
const wdFormatRTF=6
Set Word = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Word.Documents.Open("fullpathtomyfile.htm")
set ADoc=Word.ActiveDocument

fCnt = ADoc.Fields.Count
for Each field In ADoc.Fields
    field.LinkFormat.SavePictureWithDocument = True
    field.LinkFormat.BreakLink
next


 For Each shape In ADoc.Shapes 
    shape.LinkFormat.SavePictureWithDocument = True
    shape.LinkFormat.BreakLink
next

For Each iShape In ADoc.InlineShapes 
    ishape.LinkFormat.SavePictureWithDocument = True
    ishape.LinkFormat.BreakLink
Next

Word.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 "fullpathtomyfile.rtf", wdFormatRTF
Word.Documents.Close
Word.Quit
```

Best regards,
Michal